# C# how to map two section of appsetting and take the unique settings into single class object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have the following sections in my appsettings. I am using asp.net core webapi application.

```
  "security": {
    "instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "domain": "domain.com",
    "tenantId": "tenantid",
    "clientId": "sameclientid"
  },
  "powerBI": {
    "resourceUri": "resourceurl",
    "authorityUri": "authorityurl",
    "extraUrl": "https://api.powerbi.com/",
    "clientId": "sameclientid",
    "clientSecret": "secret"
  }
```

i need to map to single class

```
  class MapperClass {
    public string Instance {get;set;}
    public string Domain {get;set;}
    public string TenantId {get;set;}
    public string ClientId {get;set;}
    public string ClientSecret {get;set;}
    public string ExtraUri {get;set;}   
  }
```

Is there a way to merge or union the above two section and get it mapped to the final MapperClass?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since the source document is a JSON, you can parse it to JObject and then get requested properties like this:

```
var jsonString = "your JSON";
var jObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
var myClass = new MapperClass
{
    Instance = jObject["security"]["instance"].Value<string>(),
    ClientSecret = jObject["powerBI"]["clientSecret"].Value<string>()
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just load both sections and merge it in one class on your own.

```
var security = settings.GetSection("security") as CustomSection;
var powerBI= settings.GetSection("powerBI") as CustomSection;
MapperClass mapper = new MapperClass();
mapper.Instance = security.Instance;
```